# Java Image Flicker

Tags: java, animated-gif

Hi guys I'm working on a program that is supposed to change images upon key entry. I have used an animated gif for each image, and i'm wondering why only my left to right animated gif flickers when run. I've looked on the forums and have seen that java enables double buffering by default, but I have set it explicitly just in case, Why is this happening?

---

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
public class KeyEventAnimation extends JApplet implements KeyListener
{
    Image img;
    JLabel zil;
    int x=0, y=0, speed=10;     // x,y coordinates and how many pixels move
    JPanel pane;
    public void init( )
    {
        pane = new JPanel( );
        pane.setLayout( null );
        pane.setBackground( Color.WHITE );
        img = getImage( getCodeBase( ), "zil_walk_front.gif" );
        zil = new JLabel( new ImageIcon(img) );
        zil.setSize( img.getWidth(this), img.getHeight(this) );

        addKeyListener(this);
        pane.add( zil, 0, 0 );
        add( pane, BorderLayout.CENTER );
        setFocusable(true);
    }
    public void keyReleased( KeyEvent ke ) { }
    public void keyTyped( KeyEvent ke ) { }
    public void keyPressed( KeyEvent ke )
    {
        int code = ke.getKeyCode( );
        if( code == KeyEvent.VK_UP ){
            y -= speed;
                zil.setIcon(new ImageIcon("zil_walk_back.gif"));
       } else if ( code == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN ){
            y += speed;
                zil.setIcon(new ImageIcon("zil_walk_front.gif"));
       } else if ( code == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT ){
            x -= speed;
                zil.setIcon(new ImageIcon("zil_walk_left.gif"));
       } else if ( code == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT ){
            x += speed;
                zil.setIcon(new ImageIcon("zil_walk_right.gif"));
         }
         zil.setLocation(x,y); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe you should try an image format other than an animated gif? Do the animation yourself and use pngs or jpegs. Animated GIFs are palate based and you are relying on the java implementation to do the animation as you want it to. If you did the animation yourself you might have better luck.

Comment: *"Why is this happening?"*  There is too little information to tell, though note the following: 1) The `ImageIcon` constructor based on a `String` will not work in a `JApplet` on the net. 2) The images should be loaded in the constructor and cached, rather than loaded fresh each time a key is pressed. 3) *"java enables double buffering by default, but I have set it explicitly"*  Where?  4) That code is a mess.  Please use consistent & logical code line indents for source in future.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't run your code but it looks to me like it might be a common case of setting-the-image-to-a-value-it-already-is syndrome. When you press a key (/hold it down) it gets sent to the application/window multiple times (there is typically some delay between the first keypress and the repetitions). If you add an instance variable for remembering the state of the image (or the last key that was pressed) and then only change the image when a *different* key is pressed I think that might solve your problem.

This might not be so normally, except for the fact that you're not caching your icons (you're making a new ImageIcon object every time you change the image) so every time a key is pressed the icon is reloaded from the file. This could also cause the flicker.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I tried running the code with the actual images you are using(they are available on google image search).

Looks like something wrong with the left right images. I noticed the back and front images don't flicker. 
So if you try replacing the left and right with back and front images too, you will see that there is no flicker :)